# Rails 4 + Paperclip + Amazon S3: images are uploaded as originals, but none in styles (thumb & medium sizes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am creating a Rails app that have two resources, collectors and items, and both require images uploaded through Paperclip to Amazon s3 as storage.

I set up avatar images for collectors and it works perfectly, which means that the s3 setup/config part should be fine. However, when I use the exact same code to set up images for items, only the original images are uploaded to s3. I went to my s3 console to check the files: while thumbnail and medium folders are created, both are empty.

**Note:** Read the **Update II** section for the new code. Still have the same problem though.

Here is my code in my Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collector

  has_attached_file :item_img,
    :styles => { :thumb => '320x320>', :medium => '640x640>'},
    :storage => :s3,
    :url => ':s3_domain_url',
    :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
    :bucket => "my-project-name",
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

  has_attached_file :item_img
  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :item_img, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_attachment_file_name :item_img, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :item_img, :less_than => 1.megabytes

end
```

Here is my code in my Collector model (which works perfectly fine):

```
class Collector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  # This method associates the attribute ":avatar" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => { :thumb => '50x50>', :medium => '200x200>'},
    :default_url => ":style/missing.jpg",
    :storage => :s3,
    :url => ':s3_domain_url',
    :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
    :bucket => "my-project-name",
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_attachment_file_name :avatar, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes

  validates :email, email_format: { message: "This doesn't look like an email address. Please try again."}
end
```

What could potentially cause the problem? Let me know if you need more code from other files.

**Update I:**
The error I've been getting is 403 Access Forbidden, which is kind of surprising, considering that those files were not uploaded according to styles to the s3 console anyway.

**Update II:**
After I posted this question and read many posts about paperclip + s3 issues, I still didn't find any solution to this. So I decided to recreate new buckets for development and production on s3. While going through all the code related to paperclip and s3, I refined my code along the way so the code has changed quite a bit.

First of all, here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'httparty'
gem 'actionview', '~> 4.1.5', require: "action_view"

gem 'activesupport', '~> 4.1.6'

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'

gem 'validates_email_format_of'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'shotgun'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'launchy', '~> 2.4.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
end
```

I have a s3.rb file in `config/initializers`:

```
S3_CREDENTIALS = {
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
}
```

In order to access the `S3_CREDENTIALS`, for development, I saved all the info in my .bash_profile as following:

```
export S3_BUCKET_NAME=“my-project-name_dev”
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=“asdfasdfasdfasdf”
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=“ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF”
```

For production, I saved the above three credentials as "Config Variables" in Heroku.

For `config/initializers/paperclib.rb`, I have the following code:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

As for the models, I shortened the paths from those of the previous version, and also changed `:bucket` to make it work for both development and production:

```
class Collector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => { :thumb => '50x50>', :medium => '200x200>'},
    :default_url => ":style/missing.jpg",
    :url => ':s3_domain_url',
    :path => '/:class/:style/:filename',
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_attachment_file_name :avatar, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes

  validates :email, email_format: { message: "This doesn't look like an email address. Please try again."}
end
```

The above code for Collector model works perfectly fine in production, although it says it's `missing :bucket option` in development, which is a weird issue but not my major concern for this post. I am still having the same issue with Item:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collector

  has_attached_file :item_img,
    :styles => { :small => '320x320>', :large => '640x640>' },
    :url => ':s3_domain_url',
    :path => '/:class/:style/:filename',
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

  has_attached_file :item_img
  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :item_img, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_attachment_file_name :item_img, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/]
  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :item_img, :less_than => 1.megabytes

end
```

The weirdest thing is that, even after creating a brand new bucket, the images saved as "original" images still take the old `:path`, as defined in my old code: `:path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'`, rather than how I newly defined it: `:path => '/:class/:style/:filename'`. Maybe it's because of the paperclip default in paperclip.rb above, but I thought it would override defaults, the same way Collector model does. Still, the same old problem persists: all styles are missing, not even the folders; only originals are uploaded in the "original" folder.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Did you check the server log to see if there are any errors when the image is uploaded?

Comment: And is this in production or development?

Comment: @voidwalker I got 403 Access Forbidden Errors for the images, which I thought was a problem. However, if the images were not uploaded according to styles in the first place, of course it's forbidden to visit those links.

Comment: @voidwalker this is in production mode.

Comment: I think I had this problems with carrierwave and S3 before. What I mean is did you look at your production server log when the image is being uploaded? Look carefully at the uploading request  when user upload the image from your production server log to see if there are any warnings/errors... for my application it was because of some compatibility issue with the multiple gems I am using...And I assume in development everything works perfectly?

Comment: @voidwalker I just had an update in my question. Will you take a look? Not that it answers your question, but it's potentially useful. I'll look into both, and get back to you.

Comment: can you also update your gemfile and the paperclip initializer file ? Would be helpful to know what version of paperclip you are using. If it is older try change to the lastest one. I think your path is fine since the original image gets saved.

Comment: @voidwalker by "update" you mean I should also include both files here? My Paperclip version is 4.2.1. It's the latest version I think.

Comment: Ah yes sorry for the confusing language. Yes I mean include the files in the post.

Comment: @voidwalker I didn't check my development/local for a while, while I was trying to fix this. Now in development mode it's telling me that I'm missing `:bucket option` for both collectors & items, which is bizarre because I gave both buckets, as you can see in my code above. I don't think it's a big issue, considering I can work with collectors' images in production mode just fine. This is an annoying issue that a lot of people are having but have no solutions to, as you can see in this thread: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1073

Comment: @voidwalker I changed up my code quite a bit after I recreated id, key and buckets. So I'll have to re-edit my question before I add those files. Now I have to run for a appointment but I'll add them when I come back. Thanks for offering to read it.

Comment: No problem. There was an issue with older versions of paperclip with S3 where it looks for the original image in development path for reprocessing in production (and of course it won't find it). But since you are using the latest version it should not be the problem. And yes please update your question I will take a look again :).

Comment: @voidwalker new code is here! I feel this is such a basic issue but I'm stuck with this for very long...

Comment: Hi again! My other guess is that this has something to do with your hosting service? Since you are not directly uploading to Amazon S3 all the image processing to generate the styles are being done on your hosting server...this can potentially be a problem and causes timeouts...I see that you have the file size limit set to be 1mb though. I suggest you test the application locally under production environment, and look closely at your local server and check if the styles are being uploaded locally to amazon s3.

Comment: @voidwalker hello again! so I finally fixed my dev connection with the bucket. In dev environment,  uploading Collector images is completely fine, but none of the Item images are saved according to the styles...this is really bizarre. Maybe I should just drop the item_image column in the database and start from scratch...

Comment: so just make it clear:   Collector image is uploading everything fine to Amazon S3 locally (with the styles). How about in production server? Yes it is bizarre that item is not working but I think that is not a huge problem if you get collector to work! I would personally get collector to work perfectly first then compare item with it to see what is the culprit.

Comment: @voidwalker Hi, yes, Collector images are uploaded according to styles in both development and production, while Item images are only uploaded as originals in both development and production. I think both models have the same code, because I copied and pasted in the first place.

Comment: hmm that is strange indeed! Just one thing I notice though, in the item model , you have  has_attached_file :item_img,
    :styles => { :thumb => '320x320>', :medium => '640x640>'},
    :storage => :s3,
    :url => ':s3_domain_url',
    :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
    :bucket => "my-project-name",
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

  has_attached_file :item_img....It seems like you have has_attached_file twice, once with the style and once without.

Comment: that might be causing the issue?

Comment: @qubit YOU SAVED MY LIFE! I can't believe how much time I spent on this. I somehow thought it was a different kind of validator for attachment.

Comment: @voidwalker just in case you are still wondering about why this wasn't working. Thank you both for your help :)

Comment: lol just let you know @voidwalker is qubit. I changed my name ;)

Comment: And you are welcome! Didn't see that either. Our conversation was long indeed...

Comment: oh haha I didn't know that...thanks for your dedication to this thread then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my dedicated friend @qubit pointed out in the comment section, I have `has_attached_file :item_img` in Item model grouped with my validators, because I somehow thought it was a different form of validation and overlooked it. By removing that line, I solved the problem immediately.

Thanks again, @qubit!